# Unable to understand error while trying to return a tuple of Map

Tags: dictionary, tuples, ocaml

First of all, I have those types :

```
type position = float * float
type node = position
```

I have written those modules to make my Maps :

```
module MyMap =
  struct
    type t = Graph.node
    let compare (a1,b1) (a2,b2) =
      if a1 > a2 then 1
       else if a1 < a2 then -1
       else if b1 > b2 then 1
       else if b1 < b2 then -1
       else 0
  end

module DistMap = Map.Make(MyMap)
```

Then I wrote this function :

```
let update_distances n1 n2 dMap prevMap =
  if ((DistMap.find n2 dMap) > (DistMap.find n2 dMap) +. extract_float(dist2 n1 n2)) then
  ((DistMap.add n2 (DistMap.find n2 dMap) dMap), DistMap.add n1 prevMap)
  else (dMap,prevMap)
```

`extract_float(dist n1 n2)` return a float extracted from the distance between the `n1` and `n2` nodes.

For more clarification, dMap is a supposed that's supposed to be built like this (node, float) whereas prevMap is a Map that's supposed to be built like this : (node,node).

My goal here is to be able to return a tuple of Map, modified or not, depending on the if statement, however this is the error output I get :

```
Error: This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type
         'a DistMap.t -> 'a DistMap.t
       The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a DistMap.t -> 'a DistMap.t
```

**Update :**

The `dist2` function has type `distance`.

```
type distance = Distance of float
```

Here's `extract_float`

```
let extract_float dist =
  match dist with
    | Distance x -> x
```

It's the first time seeing this error for me, anyway to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: What is dist in `extract_float(dist n1 n2)` ? And in your code, you are using dist2 instead of dist. Moreover, which is the exact  location of the error ?

Comment: @PierreG. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 2):

The first step when dealing with type errors is to try to recover some contextual type information.

Here, the typechecker is reporting an error on the prevMap part of

```
else dMap,prevMap
```

> Error: This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type
>            'a DistMap.t -> 'a DistMap.t
>
> The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a DistMap.t -> 'a DistMap.t

Moreover, the error is a mismatch between the expected types and the actual type of the second element of the tuple. Since we are typing an `else` branch, this means that the error started in the `then` branch and only raised a conflict later. So let have a look at the `then` branch (we can ignore the `recursive occurrence` part of the message for now):

```
then DistMap.add n2 (DistMap.find n2 dMap) dMap, DistMap.add n1 prevMap
```

Since the error was raised for the second element of the tuple, we can narrow the probable root of the error to

```
 DistMap.add n1 prevMap
```

At this point, we can ask for the type of `DistMap.add`:

```
node -> 'data -> 'data DistMap.t -> 'data DistMap.t
```

In other words, from this first use of `prevMap` here, we and the typechecker can deduce that:

- prevMap is some data to be stocked in a `DistMap.t`
- the second element of the tuple is a function adding `prevMap` to a `DistMap.t`

At this point everything is fine, but then in

```
else dMap, prevMap
```

we learn that `prevMap` is a function too. So `prevMap` is both some data `'a` in a `'a DistMap.t` and an updating function with type `'a DistMap.t -> 'a DistMap.t`. The two types are incompatibles (if recursive types are not allowed). Thus the first part of the error message is

> Error: This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type 'a DistMap.t -> 'a DistMap.t

But then, what about the second part of the error message:

> The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a DistMap.t -> 'a DistMap.t

It happens that `OCaml` can make the two type compatibles with the `-rectypes` option, then the type of `prevMap` is the exotic:

```
'a DistMap.t -> 'a DistMap.t as 'a
```

which means that `prevMap` is a function that transforms `DistMap.t` which contain functions that transform `DistMap.t` which contain functions that ...

This kind of recursive types are seldom used, and when used they can mask mundane programming error. They are thus disabled by default, and the typechecker raises a `recursive occurrence` message when it infers a recursive type while `-rectype` is disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the lenghty answer and helping me understanding the nature of the problem here. It's only been a few months of coding in OCaml, what would you recommend me? Split this function in two to update the Maps separately?

Comment: It seems quite probable that you wanted to update the map in the `then` branch, and that you missed the value that you wanted to add at the `n1` key. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Jesus ... Yep that's it. I forgot to put the key... Really sorry man. Thanks.